# spring security authorize ifAllGranted documentation

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsp-tags

I'm just interested in the available attributes in spring-security:authorize tag.

In our project, we used to use tag like this:

```
<security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
```

for the access to different part of one **JSP**.

However, I read from somewhere that `ifAllGranted` is already deprecated.

So I used **SpEL** for different access levels.

But I'm still interested about finding `documentations` about these `deprecated attributes` in `authorize` tag to know how it works, and I just can't find it someone could help?

Comment: Check the [tag library sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/taglibs/src/main/resources/META-INF/security.tld) those state what should be considered deprecated and what not. But in general the static access control stuff is deprecated in favor of SpEL expression which allow for a more powerful and flexible way of securing objects.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, could you post the link as an answer and then I can finish this question ^_^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [tag library](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/taglibs/src/main/resources/META-INF/security.tld) sources those state what should be considered deprecated and what not. But in general the static access control stuff is deprecated in favor of SpEL expression which allow for a more powerful and flexible way of securing objects.

by –  [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) Aug 28 at 10:43